# \usepackage{ebgaramond} in beamer doesn't change font

Tags: beamer, fonts

I'm doing a presentation (on overleaf). From what I read, using the commands

```
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

change the fonts for article type documents. While the command ebgaramond-maths worked, the text font remains the standard one. How can I change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beamer is a bit special with regards to fonts. It uses sans serif font by default and uses most of the text font for math.

If you want to use a serif font, like `ebgaramond`, you can use the `serif` font theme.

To make sure that your math font is used and not substituted with glyphs from the text font, you can combine this with the `professionalfonts` fonts theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage{ebgaramond} 
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
  
  \[
  abc
  \]
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]